# Add columns vertically in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a table 'test' like this-

```
        M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7        
    A   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7        
    B   B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  .        
    C   C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  .   .        
    D   D1  D2  D3  D4  .   .   .        
    E   E1  E2  E3  .   .   .   .        
    F   F1  F2  .   .   .   .   .        
    G   G1  .   .   .   .   .   .
```

I want to add the columns in the following way-

```
    M1=(A1+B1+C1+D1+E1+F1+G1)     
    M2=(A2+B2+C2+D2+E2+F2)+(A1+B1+C1+D1+E1+F1)     
    M3=(A3+B3+C3+D3+E3)+(A2+B2+C2+D2+E2)+(A1+B1+C1+D1+E1)     
    M4=(A4+B4+C4+D4)+(A3+B3+C3+D3)+(A2+B2+C2+D2)+(A1+B1+C1+D1)     
    M5=(A5+B5+C5)+(A4+B4+C4)+(A3+B3+C3)+(A2+B2+C2)+(A1+B1+C1)     
    M6=(A6+B6)+(A5+B5)+(A4+B4)+(A3+B3)+(A2+B2)+(A1+B1)     
    M7=(A7)+(A6)+(A5)+(A4)+(A3)+(A2)+(A1)
```

The number of rows and columns may increase or decrease in my table, ie, my columns could be from M1 to MN. I want to take the sum till MN in the same way.
I am not sure how to even start with this problem. Please help.

Comment: What output do you want?  Just one observation with N columns? Or did you want some type of matrix? Can you add an example with numbers? Perhaps for N=3 or 4 ?

Comment: Do you have PROC IML available?

Comment: I want the output like this-
Column Sum
M1 (A1+B1+C1+D1+E1+F1+G1)     
M2 (A2+B2+C2+D2+E2+F2)+(A1+B1+C1+D1+E1+F1)     
M3 (A3+B3+C3+D3+E3)+(A2+B2+C2+D2+E2)+(A1+B1+C1+D1+E1)     
M4 (A4+B4+C4+D4)+(A3+B3+C3+D3)+(A2+B2+C2+D2)+(A1+B1+C1+D1)     
M5 (A5+B5+C5)+(A4+B4+C4)+(A3+B3+C3)+(A2+B2+C2)+(A1+B1+C1)     
M6 (A6+B6)+(A5+B5)+(A4+B4)+(A3+B3)+(A2+B2)+(A1+B1)     
M7 (A7)+(A6)+(A5)+(A4)+(A3)+(A2)+(A1)

Comment: For each column in my test table, I want the sum according to the formulas given below that. The no of columns in my test table can vary from M1 to MN.

Comment: Please add the output to the question, via an edit. Trying to determine the format in a comment isn't easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.  I sum both the rows and the columns.

I work from the outside in so that I don't have to make a temporary copies of the column sums.

First:
Sum the numbers in the square (sum the columns).

Second: Subtract the row rums for the outside values.

```
data have;
input row $ M1-M7;
datalines;
A   1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
B   2  2  2  2  2  2  . 
C   3  3  3  3  3  .  .
D   4  4  4  4  .  .  .
E   5  5  5  .  .  .  .
F   6  6  .  .  .  .  .
G   7  .  .  .  .  .  .
;
run;

data row_sums;
set have end=last;
array M[7] ;
array RS[7];
retain RS:;
rs[_n_] = sum(of M[*]);
if last;
keep rs1-rs7;
run;

proc summary data=have;
var M:;
output out=col_sums(drop=_type_ _freq_) sum=;
run;

data want;
merge col_sums row_sums;
array M[7] ;
array RS[7];

do i=7 to 2 by -1;
    do j=i-1 to 1 by -1;
        M[i] = M[i] + M[j];
    end;
    do j=7 to 9-i by -1;
        M[i] = M[i] - RS[j];
    end;
end;
drop RS: i j;
run;
```

I get:

```
                     M1    M2    M3    M4    M5    M6    M7

                      28    42    45    40    30    18     7
```

Answer (score 0):

So for M1 (let's call this column 1) you want the sum of the values in the 'N x 1' sub-matrix. And for MN (column N) you want the sum of the value in the `1 x N` sub-matrix.  So for MX (column X) you want the sum of the values in the `(N+1-X) x X` sub-matrix.

It would be easier if you defined the rectangles the other way since SAS will process the values by rows by default.  But we can build them up into an array and then output them at the end of the data step.

```
%let n=7;
data want;
 set have end=eof;
 array m m1-m&n;
 array S (&n) _temporary_ ;
 array result (&n) _temporary_ ;
 row+1;
 col=&n+1-row;
 * build up column totals ;
 do i=1 to col ;
   s(i)=sum(0,s(i),m(i));
 end;
 * add across to get total for this column ;
 do i=1 to col ;
   result(col)=sum(0,result(col),s(i));
 end;
 if eof then do;
   * copy back to the "m" variables ;
   do i=1 to &n ;
     m(i) = result(i);
   end;
   output;
   put (m1-m&n) (=);
 end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single data step solution. The idea is track the cumulative sum of each row and add it to the current cumulative sum of the column.

```
%let n = 7;
data want;
do until (eof);
    set have end=eof;
    array m(*) m1-m&n;
    array ms(&n);

    _sum = 0; * reset cum row sum;
    do _i = 1 to dim(m);
        if missing(m(_i)) then leave;
        _sum + m(_i); * cumulative sum of row;
        ms(_i) + _sum; * cumulative sum of column;
    end;
end;
output;
drop row m1-m&n _:;
run;
```

[image]